# Non-standard evaluation of expressions in S4 context

Tags: r, expression, r-s4, delayed-execution

This is borrowed from [shiny's](http://shiny.rstudio.com/) function [`exprToFunction`](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/master/R/utils.R#L382) which is used in their [`reactive`](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/master/R/reactives.R#L437) function.

### Actual question

How can I delay the evaluation of an expression (e.g. specified via arg `expr`) in order to "capture" its content when calling a S4 method (as opposed to a standard R function)?

### Example

Note that `x_1` does **not** exist yet, that's why we want to delay the evaluation of `expr` and just "capture" its content.

Function `captureExpression`:

```
captureExpression <- function(
  expr,
  caller_offset = 1,
  brackets = TRUE
) {
  out <- eval(substitute(substitute(expr)), parent.frame(caller_offset))
  if (brackets && class(out) != "{") {
    out <- substitute({CODE}, list(CODE = out))
  }
  out
}

captureExpression(x_1 * 2)
# {
#     x_1 * 2
# }
```

Passing **unevaluated** `expr` through works when calling a standard R function:

```
foo <- function(expr) {
  captureExpression(expr = expr)
}

foo(x_1 * 2)
# {
#     x_1 * 2
# }
```

Passing **unevaluated** `expr` through does not work when calling an S4 method:

```
setGeneric(
  name = "bar",
  signature = c(
    "expr"
  ),
  def = function(
    expr,
    ...
  ) {
    standardGeneric("bar")       
  }
)
setMethod(
  f = "bar", 
  signature = signature(
    expr = "ANY"
  ), 
  definition = function(
    expr,
    ...
  ) {
  captureExpression(expr = expr, ...)    
})
```

Applying the S4 method:

```
bar(x_1 * 2)
# Error in bar(x_1 * 2) : 
#   error in evaluating the argument 'expr' in selecting a method for function 'bar': Error: 
# object 'x_1' not found

bar(x_1 * 2, caller_offset = 2)
# Error in bar(x_1 * 2, caller_offset = 2) :
#   error in evaluating the argument 'expr' in selecting a method for function 'bar': Error: 
# object 'x_1' not found

bar(x_1 * 2, caller_offset = 3)
# Error in bar(x_1 * 2, caller_offset = 3) :
#   error in evaluating the argument 'expr' in selecting a method for function 'bar': Error: 
# object 'x_1' not found
```

I guess this has to do with the way the method dispatch is actually carried out. However, maybe there's a way that this can be done anyways.