# Lexical scoping / calling stack issue: R fails to recognize an argument's default value

Tags: r, arguments, default, stack-trace, lexical-scope

This is sort of the strangest thing I ever encountered in R.

Is it possible, that certain argument names (`lazy` in my case) are special/reserved and thus would lead to unexpected behavior when a calling stack is involved that spreads across functions of three different packages: `optionr::setAnywhereOptions()` calls `nestr::setNested()` calls `reactr::setShinyReactive()`?

Consider the following example/situation (also described in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Rappster/reactr/issues/28))

### Adapted from this [unit test](https://github.com/Rappster/optionr/blob/master/tests/testthat/test-setAnywhereOption.r#L228) in package `optionr`

```
require("devtools")
devtools::install_github("Rappster/conditionr")
devtools::install_github("Rappster/typr")
devtools::install_github("Rappster/nestr")
devtools::install_github("Rappster/reactr", ref = "bug-28")

devtools::install_github("Rappster/optionr")
require("optionr")

path <- file.path(tempdir(), "test")
create(path, description = getOption("devtools.desc"), check = FALSE,
  rstudio = TRUE)
setwd(path)

container <- initializeOptionContainer(overwrite = TRUE)  
setAnywhereOption(id = "x_1", value = TRUE, reactive = TRUE)
getAnywhereOption(id = "x_1")
setAnywhereOption(id = "x_2", 
  value = reactr::reactiveExpression(
    !getAnywhereOption(id = "x_1")
  ), 
  reactive = TRUE
)

getAnywhereOption(id = "x_1")
getAnywhereOption(id = "x_2")
```

Note the status messages that I included for [debugging](https://github.com/Rappster/reactr/blob/bug-28/R/setShinyReactive.r#L196):

```
DEBUG/push/before
[1] FALSE
DEBUG/lazy/before
Error in print(lazy) : argument is missing, with no default
DEBUG/is_lazy/before
[1] FALSE
DEBUG/lazy/after
[1] FALSE
```

For some reason, for this very calling stack structure, function `reactr::setShinyReactive()` does not seem to recognize the default value for `lazy` anymore while others (e.g. that of `push`) seem to be recognized just fine.

To be more precise, without my workaround (see below), R would complain when reaching [this code section](https://github.com/Rappster/reactr/blob/bug-28/R/setShinyReactive.r#L257). However, as you can see, the default value **is** defined and it also works just fine if the function is called stand-alone or from within [`nestr::setNested()`](https://github.com/Rappster/nestr/blob/master/tests/testthat/test-setNested.r#L221).

### Workaround

When I change the argument name from `lazy` to `is_lazy` (or just include `is_lazy` as well and then run `lazy <- is_lazy` in the body), everything works just fine (see debug output above).

See *DEBUG* section in [`reactr::setShinyReactive()`](https://github.com/Rappster/reactr/blob/bug-28/R/setShinyReactive.r#L196)

### Wildly guessing what's going on here

The first thing that comes to my mind is that this must have *something* to do with the lexical scoping mechanism as the behavior does not appear for "simple function call stacks".

The second guess is that maybe the S4 mechanism also causes some trouble here. Maybe also related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26462704/non-standard-delayed-evaluation-of-expressions-in-s4-context)?

Comment: There are lots of "function.lazy" methods and even a package `lazy` . Perhaps you need to take things a lot slower. Further, it's a bit uncool to expect us to read and debug several layers of your own personal packages.  If you can produce a standalone function which depends only on standard CRAN packages, perhaps we can figure out what you're trying to solve in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not expecting anything - just politely asking for help and I'm always very grateful for those taking the time and effort. It's totally fine if you don't want to dig through the code. But I don"t see why the fact that it's mostly my own code should be of any matter here. Plus, I think the issue arises from the very fact that this is a layered arrangement and not some very simplified stand-alone example. But I'll try to further simplify.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have to admit: that was a really stupid mistake. I unintentionally had a trailing `,` in the call to `nestr::setNested()` inside `optionr::setAnywhereOption()`

Here's a much simpler illustration:

### Definitions

```
setGeneric(
  name = "setAnywhereOption",
  signature = "id",
  def = function(id, ...) standardGeneric("setAnywhereOption")      
)
setMethod(
  f = "setAnywhereOption", 
  signature = signature(id = "character"), 
#  definition = function(id, ...) setNested(id = id)
  ## --> works
#  definition = function(id, ...) setNested(id = id, ...)
  ## --> works
  definition = function(id, ...) setNested(id = id,)
  ## --> this leads to things get messed up with argument's default values
  ## --> so the trailing `,` was causing the problem!
)
setGeneric(
  name = "setNested",
  signature = "id",
  def = function(id, ...) standardGeneric("setNested")       
)
setMethod(
  f = "setNested", 
  signature = signature(id = "character"), 
  definition = function(id, ...) {

  if (FALSE) {  
    ## Omitted 
  } else {
    setShinyReactive(id = basename(id), ...)
  }

})
setShinyReactive <- function(
  id,
  lazy = FALSE,
  is_lazy = FALSE,
  push = FALSE,
  typed = FALSE,
  strict_set = c(0, 1, 2),
  ...
  ) {

  ###########
  ## DEBUG ##    
  ###########
  message("DEBUG/setShinyReactive/threedots")
  print(list(...))
  message("DEBUG/setShinyReactive/push")        
  print(push)    
  message("DEBUG/setShinyReactive/lazy")    
  try(print(lazy))
  ## --> strangely, R does not seem to like the name `lazy` 
  message("DEBUG/setShinyReactive/is_lazy")    
  print(is_lazy)
  ## --> this works
  lazy <- is_lazy
  message("DEBUG/setShinyReactive/lazy")    
  print(lazy)

  TRUE

}
```

### Apply

```
setAnywhereOption(id = "test")
# DEBUG/setShinyReactive/threedots
# list()
# DEBUG/setShinyReactive/push
# [1] FALSE
# DEBUG/setShinyReactive/lazy
# Error in print(lazy) : argument is missing, with no default
# DEBUG/setShinyReactive/is_lazy
# [1] FALSE
# DEBUG/setShinyReactive/lazy
# [1] FALSE
# [1] TRUE
setAnywhereOption(id = "test", push = TRUE)
setAnywhereOption(id = "test", lazy = TRUE)
```

### Solution

Removing the trailing `,` in the method definition of `setAnywhereOption()`:

```
setMethod(
  f = "setAnywhereOption", 
  signature = signature(id = "character"), 
  definition = function(id, ...) setNested(id = id)
  ## --> works
#  definition = function(id, ...) setNested(id = id,)
  ## --> this leads to things get messed up with argument's default values
  ## --> so the trailing `,` was causing the problem!
)

setAnywhereOption(id = "test")
# DEBUG/setShinyReactive/threedots
# list()
# DEBUG/setShinyReactive/push
# [1] FALSE
# DEBUG/setShinyReactive/lazy
# [1] FALSE
# DEBUG/setShinyReactive/is_lazy
# [1] FALSE
# DEBUG/setShinyReactive/lazy
# [1] FALSE
# [1] TRUE
```

Now it works just fine